# read and write to content - visual studio c# xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

my solution contains a txt file. The build action is VS is set to content.

I can access this file by using

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///textfile.txt"));
```

But I can't write anything into this file.

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "abcd");
```

I always get the error:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Do I have to set the build action to embedded ressource? But then I can't access this file as StorageFile.

Comment: Add write and read permissions on folder where you save the file, maybe you should add permission on file too

Comment: This file is included in the VS solution itself. How can I set read/write permissions for those files?

Comment: you can go to the folder where is your solution (app data, bin, scripts...) and righ click on the folder where is the files, Properties>Security and add the permissions

Comment: you're talking about the windows permissions? The app runs under my user and this user has, of course, write permissions. But what has the Windows persmissions to do with files, that are included in the solution? They should have there own permissions. For normaly they should be under AppDate during runtime. Or am I completeley wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps install location is read only. To write your file [CopyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_CopyAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFolder_) it to ApplicationData.LocalFolder on first run (or the first time the app needs it) and then you’ll have a writable user-specific file.

```
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///textfile.txt"));
var copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(copiedFile, "abcd");
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Already thought that it might be something like that. Wasn't sure that it is right only. Thought I missed something. Thanks Rob